# How do I connect my IPad Air 1 to the internet via ethernet without creating an AP?

Tags: network, usb, ethernet, ipad

How do I connect my iPad Air to the internet with an ethernet cable without creating an access point or a wireless signal/hotspot of any kind?

My first attempt was a duplicate of [this fella](http://www.gottabemobile.com/2014/08/28/how-to-connect-an-ipad-to-ethernet/)

But, there's a couple problems with that setup:

1. Two of the core components he said are "Needed" link to non-existent websites (Lightning to USB Camera Adapter & USB Ethernet Adapter)
2. Every other USB 2.0 ethernet dongle I purchase has a driver that needs to be installed, which isn't easy with the iPad
3. Even in his setup iPad says it cannot connect to the device

I'm using these:

- Insignia USB 2.0 Powered Hub
- [Insignia USB 2.0 Ethernet Adapter](http://www.insigniaproducts.com/products/computer-speakers-accessories/NS-PU98505.html)
- ASUS Dual-band Wireless-AC1900 Gigabit Router
- iPad Air (with the latest software updates)
- Lightning to USB Camera Adapter

Comment: I can confirm that (tested during the week of 11/9/2015) it works using the actual APPLE Brand USB Camera adapter and APPLE Brand USB Ethernet RJ45 adapter and a powered USB hub. I tested it on iOS 8 and 9 and it works. It does give a message that the accessory is not supported when you first connect but touch OK and about 10 seconds later the internet connection will be available. I can also confirm that as soon as I substituted the APPLE ethernet adapter with a Cables Unlimited brand it did NOT work. My goal was to not only get the internet / network connection working, but also to try to ge

Answer (score 1):

You almost certainly need the geniune [Apple USB Ethernet adapter](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MC704LL/A/apple-usb-ethernet-adapter), because it's probably the only USB Ethernet adapter that iOS has drivers for. Even if you find another adapter that uses the same chipset, Apple's drivers probably won't load unless the dongle identifies itself as an Apple product.

Comment: That's what I assumed the problem was, and I also assumed there was no app or anything that could install any sort of driver to interface with other dongles.
I'll try the Apple USB Ethernet Adapter you linked when I get home, but, the description of that adapter says its designed for Macbook Air computers, so will it work with an iPad Air?

Comment: @JoePearson Well, "someone on the internet says it works", and we know Apple already has a Darwin (OS X / iOS Unix/kernel layer) driver for it, so it's most plausible that they'd built that driver into iOS. Which is better evidence than we have for any other USB Ethernet dongle.